# RatingBar not working

Tags: android, ratingbar

i have a simple ratingbar in my app, but when i touch the stars to rate do nothing it should be easy but it's not working...

I've tried several tutorials but also didn't work.

Here is my code:

Layout code:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:stepSize="1.0" 
        android:rating="2.0"
        android:numStars="5" 
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
```

Activity:

```
public final class ViewActivity extends Activity implements OnRatingBarChangeListener {

RatingBar ratingbar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
        boolean fromUser) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Float.toString(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

I also tried to do:

Activity:

```
public final class ViewActivity extends Activity implements OnRatingBarChangeListener {

RatingBar ratingbar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
OnRatingBarChangeListener rating = new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {    

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Float.toString(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    final RatingBar sBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    sBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(rating);
}
```

And Also:

```
public final class ViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
RatingBar rating = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);// create RatingBar object
    rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Float.toString(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I have used the debugger and put a breakpoint to the Toast and when I touch the stars doesn't enter to the method and didn't show the Toast either.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#C2C2A3">

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="OK" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    Button btn;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
   btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

   // Set ChangeListener to Rating Bar
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
         boolean fromUser) {

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
       });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  float rating=ratingBar.getRating(); 
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
});

 }  
 }
```

Also, check below links :

1. http://www.javatpoint.com/android-rating-bar-example
2. http://webtutsdepot.com/2011/08/20/android-sdk-tutorial-rating-bar-example/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Property isIndicator must be false.

You can programatically do that with a setter:

```
    RatingBar ratingBar = findViewById(R.id.YOURID);
    ratingBar.setIsIndicator(false);
```

Or in xml property:

```
    android:isIndicator="false"
```

Make sure you are getting the right RatingBar.